# How do I integrate a Gaussian using Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

I can't think of what I might be doing wrong: This is the code I've been using, followed by the error I'm getting (thanks in advance for your time):

```py
import scipy.integrate
import numpy as np

integrand= lambda x:((x**1)*(np.exp((-1*(x - 5)**2) / (2 * 10**2)))

intmom = scipy.integrate.quad(integrand, 1, 10)
print(intmom)
```

---

Error:

> File "", line 3
> intmom = scipy.integrate.quad(integrand, 1, 10)
> ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing ) on the previous line it should be

```
integrand= lambda x:((x**1)*(np.exp((-1*(x - 5)**2) / (2 * 10**2))))
```

Output:

```
(47.53743192883985, 5.277715145894907e-13)
```